# Playframework 2.0 scala Akka Websocket error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

Got this error while experimenting with the playframework version 2.0.4 with scala:

**value foreach is not a member of object akka.actor.IO.Iteratee**

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator
import akka.actor.IO.Iteratee
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka


object Application extends Controller {

 def index = WebSocket.async[String] {
    Akka.future{
      val out = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
      val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
        msg =>
          out.push(msg)
      }

      (in,out)
    }

  }


}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import akka.actor.IO.Iteratee
```

↓

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
```

Comment: you should put just a bit more effort into your answer. just put some quick explanation - otherwise your answers are catched by spam filters